# How do you create a "next page" link in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a button to my site which links to the next page of posts. I'm looking for a way to add an HTML link to the button so it actually works.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_link_pages

I believe that explains what I want, but I'm not having any luck trying to get those snippets to work.

My button looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="next_page">Next Page</a>
```

How can I link the button to the next page function in Wordpress?

EDIT:

My problem is I can't figure out how to associate this code with a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two 'built-in' ways of doing this in Wordpress:

1) If you need access to the link as a PHP variable, try Using [get_next_posts_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link)

```
<?php $nextLink = get_next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages ); ?>
<?php $previousLink = get_previous_posts_link( $label ); ?>
```

From here the links are stored in variables and you can do whatever you'd like with them.

2) Otherwise use these:

```
<?php next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( $label ); ?>
```

Where $label is the name of the link ( "Next Page" in your case ) and $max_pages is the max number of pages (if you want a limit), that the link shows up on.

If you want to style these, without having to enclose them inside another DIV, use [Wordpress Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

```
function apply_my_next_link_style ( ){
    return 'class="button"';
}
apply_filters( 'next_posts_link_attributes', 'apply_my_next_link_style' )
```

3) If you need even more control you can try this, from the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0) for the above functions:

```
if ( !is_single() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . next_posts( 0, false ) . "\" $attr>" . preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', "Next Page") . '</a>';
}
```

Also, I would suggest asking these types of questions over at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Put this into a div and styled with CSS into a button.

Answer (score 0):

Is necesary [Snippets](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/posts/next-previous-links/) , visit this and this solve

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php next_posts_link('Older Posts'); ?>   
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts'); ?>
```

Comment: My problem is I can't figure out how to associate this code with a button. My button code in the OP didn't work:
    <a href="#" class="next_page">Next Page</a>

Comment: @Stn `<a>` is an anchor, not a button which is `<input type="button"/>`